# Meaning of the sentence

Tags: sentence

"Eliot Ness hounded out graft in all forms—he even helped nab Al Capone".

I know "hound" means "follow and pursue", but no meaning of "graft" in the dictionary seems to fit the sentence.

Comment: "the acquisition of money, power, etc, by dishonest or unfair means, esp by taking advantage of a position of trust" [graft](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/graft)

Comment: Your 'the dictionary' needs a bit of help. TheMathemagician found the answer in 'the dictionary' known as Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003

Answer (score 3):

Graft in this sense means "Money or cash obtained through criminal activity such as fraud or being paid by someone to 'keep quiet' if they have seen a criminal action.